# How to use dynamic localization in an asp .net web application

Tags: c#, localization

I have added a resourcefile named language.resx to my App_GlobalResources folder, which enables me to access strings like App_GlobalResoureces.Language.MyString. How do I make this dynamic? So if I have a string called ResourceID, how do I pull the correct resource from the resource file?

so far I tried this:

```
string s = "MyString";

System.Resources.ResourceManager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("App_GlobalResources.Language", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
string lang = mngr.GetString(s);
```

but this is not working (it says it cannot find the namespace or something).

It has been suggested to use a database for this, but I dont want this since its just a couple of enums I want to translate.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
string s = "MyString";
var mngr = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("Resources.Language", 
    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
string lang = mngr.GetString(s);
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed, that could well work, I found another solution (see above) before I saw yours. Thanks.

Comment: It will be great if you post it as answer and mark it, or mark another one if achieves the same. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's embarassing easy. Why is this extremely simple stuff always so hard to find

The correct code is:

```
App_GlobalResources.Language.ResourceManager.GetString("MyString");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is proxy code generated by Visual Studio. If you want to locate the file yourself (what I thought you meant by dynamic) you'd do it as in the code sinnpet aobe. Actually, I got this code by copying the contents of the "get" accessor of the properties geenrated for resource files :)